# Alterar a imagem de uma section utilizando javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho uma `section` que contém em seu arquivo `.css` o seguinte:

```css
.cid-qTkA127IK8 {
   background-image: url("../../../assets/images/background4.jpg");
}
```

Porém, meu objetivo é ao invés de utilizar o *CSS* para inserir imagens, eu gostaria de **inserir o link de uma *URL* em um `input form`** e, através do *Javascript*, adicionar essa imagem de fundo da `tag section`.

A fim de testar os seletores do *Javascript*, tentei inicialmente alterar a cor e deu certo, porém, não consigo alterar a imagem...

```html
<section class="cid-qTkA127IK8 mbr-fullscreen mbr-parallax-background" id="header2-1">
    <script>
        document.getElementById('header2-1').style.backgroundImage ="https://jornaldoempreendedor.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/xd_070318_454_4243.jpg";
    </script>
</section>
```

Inclusive tentei alterar a imagem selecionando o seletor de classe do *Javascript*, mas mesmo assim não obtive sucesso.

Outra maneira também, que tentei alterar o endereço da imagem foi através do uso do seletor src, da seguinte maneira:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("cid-qTkA127IK8").src= "https://jornaldoempreendedor.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/xd_070318_454_4243.jpg";
```

Igualmente, não tive resultados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa colocar o atributo **url()** e inserir o link dentro para a imagem renderizar, mas, o que quer fazer não é muito bacana, pois dependendo a imagem pode demorar a carregar, o mais indicado é deixar as imagens em uma pasta local mesmo:

```js
document.getElementById('header2-1').style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://jornaldoempreendedor.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/xd_070318_454_4243.jpg")';
```

```css
#header2-1 {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<section class="cid-qTkA127IK8 mbr-fullscreen mbr-parallax-background" id="header2-1">
</section>
```

Comment: Cheguei atrasado :D

Comment: @hugocsl Eu te esperei ;)

Comment: vale lembrar também que para utilizar a função getElementsByClassName é necessário informar a posição (pois ela retorna um array). Caso seja o único elemento com essa classe, utilizaria document.getElementsByClassName("cid-qTkA127IK8")[0]